# Optaplanner support MDVRP (Multiple Depot VRP)?

Tags: optaplanner

How can I implement vrp **when different vehicles are initially in a different place**?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason why `Vehicle` and `Depot` are separate classes in the vehicle routing example. Just have multipe depots, one per starting location of a set of vehicles. Or remove the `depot` class entirely and just give every `Vehicle` a starting `Location`.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey